# Entity Framework EDMX file local and live

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have created a project in MVC By using Entity Framework. I had added a Edmx file of my local database, now I want to connect to my live database.

Now I want to keep both local and live database in my project, so I can use any database as per my web configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your local and live database have the same structure, your edmx file will work for both the live and dev databases. You simply need to update your connection string to point at the live database.

Your Connection string can be found in the web.config file in your MVC Project.

Example local connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbname.mdf;Initial Catalog=dbo;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Example sql server 2008 connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=DatabaseServerName;Database=dbname;User Id=username; Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
```

Check out [http://Connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) for more connection string examples

Comment: Thanx for the Reply..                                                                                 ok. But What about the EDMX Entity File EDMX file?IT will be  2 EDMX Local and live. And when i add the live EDmx file its class and all get change.. So how to maintain the two edmx Files in the Projetc.

Comment: @Rimple you only need to add one EDMX file as the data bases should be the same. The connection string in your config file lets you set which database to connect to. Since the databases are identical, your edmx will work for either.